# How to split/sort the dataframe into multiple ones in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a text file containing some observational data where the daily observations are separated by rows starting from #. How can I group the data by day/month?

I am attaching the text file here.
[Data Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-o_M_nOSFU4J39Bczs4VfsCONrM-9l5w/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import sys

data = pd.read_csv("./INM00043333-data.txt",delimiter='\s+')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How do I proceed after that?

Comment: how about manually reading the file line by line using the csv module.

Comment: @el_oso the file contains around 100000 lines of text and some files even contain 10 million. Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy `file.txt` extracted from yours:

```
#INM00043333 2016 02 06 06 9999    7 ncdc-gts   116667   927167
10 -9999  92500 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    50    41 
10 -9999  85000 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    60    36 
01 -9999  -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    45    31 
30 -9999  -9999   300 -9999 -9999 -9999    35    87 
30 -9999  -9999   600 -9999 -9999 -9999    50    46 
30 -9999  -9999   900 -9999 -9999 -9999    55    36 
30 -9999  -9999  1800 -9999 -9999 -9999    65    31 
#INM00043333 2016 02 06 12 9999    7 ncdc-gts   116667   927167
10 -9999  92500 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    40    77 
10 -9999  85000 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    25   108 
01 -9999  -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    45    41 
30 -9999  -9999   300 -9999 -9999 -9999    50    57 
30 -9999  -9999   600 -9999 -9999 -9999    55    67 
30 -9999  -9999   900 -9999 -9999 -9999    40    93 
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999    25   108 
#INM00043333 2016 02 06 18 9999    7 ncdc-gts   116667   927167
10 -9999  92500 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    40    77 
10 -9999  85000 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    25   108 
01 -9999  -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999    45    41 
30 -9999  -9999   300 -9999 -9999 -9999    50    57 
30 -9999  -9999   600 -9999 -9999 -9999    55    67 
30 -9999  -9999   900 -9999 -9999 -9999    40    93 
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999    25   108
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", delimiter="\s+", header=None)

# Rename columns
df.columns = [f"col{i}" for i in range(df.shape[1])]

# Add year, month and day as new columns, and fill missing values
df.loc[df["col0"].str.startswith("#"), "year"] = df.loc[
    df["col0"].str.startswith("#"), "col1"
]
df.loc[df["col0"].str.startswith("#"), "month"] = df.loc[
    df["col0"].str.startswith("#"), "col2"
]
df.loc[df["col0"].str.startswith("#"), "day"] = df.loc[
    df["col0"].str.startswith("#"), "col3"
]
df[["year", "month", "day"]] = (
    df[["year", "month", "day"]].fillna(method="ffill").astype(int)
)

# Cleanup
df = (
    df[~df["col0"].str.startswith("#")].reset_index(drop=True).dropna(how="all", axis=1)
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   col0  col1   col2  col3  col4  ...  col7  col8  year  month  day
0    10 -9999  92500 -9999 -9999  ...    50    41  2016      2    6
1    10 -9999  85000 -9999 -9999  ...    60    36  2016      2    6
2    01 -9999  -9999 -9999 -9999  ...    45    31  2016      2    6
3    30 -9999  -9999   300 -9999  ...    35    87  2016      2    6
4    30 -9999  -9999   600 -9999  ...    50    46  2016      2    6
5    30 -9999  -9999   900 -9999  ...    55    36  2016      2    6
6    30 -9999  -9999  1800 -9999  ...    65    31  2016      2    6
7    10 -9999  92500 -9999 -9999  ...    40    77  2016      2    6
8    10 -9999  85000 -9999 -9999  ...    25   108  2016      2    6
9    01 -9999  -9999 -9999 -9999  ...    45    41  2016      2    6
10   30 -9999  -9999   300 -9999  ...    50    57  2016      2    6
11   30 -9999  -9999   600 -9999  ...    55    67  2016      2    6
12   30 -9999  -9999   900 -9999  ...    40    93  2016      2    6
13   30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999  ...    25   108  2016      2    6
14   10 -9999  92500 -9999 -9999  ...    40    77  2016      2    6
15   10 -9999  85000 -9999 -9999  ...    25   108  2016      2    6
16   01 -9999  -9999 -9999 -9999  ...    45    41  2016      2    6
17   30 -9999  -9999   300 -9999  ...    50    57  2016      2    6
18   30 -9999  -9999   600 -9999  ...    55    67  2016      2    6
19   30 -9999  -9999   900 -9999  ...    40    93  2016      2    6
20   30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999  ...    25   108  2016      2    6
```